# My x86 assembly code loop is throwing a seg fault

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, cygwin, x86-64

I'm doing an x86 assembly project for class and we're supposed to implement a heap of personnel records. The `call heap_swap` line is giving me trouble. If I uncomment it, it throws a seg fault. However, the *heap_swap* function works fine no matter how I test it. I've really racked my brain and would appreciate any help anyone can give!

```
sift_up1:
    
    
    # ecx = i
    # rdx = address to heap
    # r9 = address to heap[i]
    # rax = offset of id
    # r8 = address for heap[i].id_number
    # r10d = heap[i].id_number
    # r11d = index of parent
    # rdx = address for parent id number
    # ebx = heap[parent].id_number
    pushq   %rbp         
    movq    %rsp, %rbp   

    subq    $32, %rsp
    
    pushq   %rbx            #a section to keep track of all the callee saved registers
    pushq   %rdi            #that need to be restored
    
    
    leaq    offset_of_id(%rip), %rax        #put the id offset into a register
    leaq    heap(%rip), %rdx
    
    jmp     LOOP_TOP            

LOOP_TOP:   
    cmpl    $0, %ecx                #Check if i=0, if so jump to exit loop
    je      EXIT_LOOP
    
    movl    $8, %r9d            
    imull   %ecx, %r9d          #finding heap[i]
    addq    (%rdx), %r9
                                

    movq    %r9, %r8            #r8 contains heap[i]
    addq    (%rax), %r8         #add id offset, it becomes heap[i].id_number
    movl    (%r8), %r10d        #dereference id_number and place it into r10d
    
    movl    %ecx, %r11d         #find the index of the parent of i
    subl    $1, %r11d
    shrl    $1, %r11d   
    
    
    movl    $8, %edi            
    imull   %r11d, %edi         
    addq    (%rdx), %rdi        #rdi holds the address of heap[parent]
    addq    (%rax), %rdi        #rdi holds the address of heap[parent].id_number
    
    
    movl    (%rdi), %ebx        #ebx holds the heap[parent].id_number
    
    cmpl    %ebx, %r10d
    jle     EXIT_LOOP
    
    pushq   %rdx
    movq    %r11, %rdx          #put the indexes in the correct parameter functions
                                
#   call    heap_swap           #call heap_swap
    
    popq    %rdx
    movl    %r11d, %ecx         #modify i
    jmp     LOOP_TOP            #jump to loop top
```

Comment: There is no way for that instruction to be the immediate cause of the seg fault, which means that the only possibility is that instruction changes the execution of the rest of the program.  First, find the actual offending instruction -- the debugger can tell you which exact instruction it is  -- that instruction will have a memory reference, and be using a bad address. Next, find who made the bad address.  Alternately, you can single step from the beginning.  Test with the smallest possible input, then when working, larger.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you! Can I ask what debugger you're using?

Comment: `push` / `call` is always very suspicious in code for the Windows x64 calling convention.  The callee owns 32 bytes of "shadow space" above the return address, and can step on it.  Unless `heap_swap` is hand-written in asm so you know it doesn't use that space.  Save/restore another call-preserved register like R12..R15 to use instead of RDX, to hold whatever variable you have that needs to survive across calls.  There may be other bugs, too; use a debugger.  (I don't use Windows so I don't have a recommendation.  I use GDB on Linux; it's primitive but mostly works with `layout reg`.)

Comment: GDB is the debugger available as Cygwin package

Comment: Good debugger for 64bit Windows is https://x64dbg.com/